# getting false even after setting true in sharedpreferences android

Tags: android

```
 public void inValidMobileNumber() {

    if (TokenUtils.isInvalidDob() ) {
        startActivity(new Intent(PersonalInfo.this,PassTwo.class));
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.dashboard_right_from,R.anim.dashboard_right_to);
        TokenUtils.setisInvalidDob(false);
    }
    else {
        TokenUtils.setisInvalidDob(true);
        Intent intent = new Intent(PersonalInfo.this, MobileNumber.class);
        intent.putExtra("reportId", reportId);
        intent.putExtra("activityCode", CreditMantriConstants.TELL_US_MORE_ACTIVITY);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.dashboard_right_from, R.anim.dashboard_right_to);
    }

}
```

public static void setisInvalidDob(Boolean dob){
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(CreditMantriApplication.getCreditMantri());
        final SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();
        edit.putBoolean("dob",dob);
        edit.apply();
    }

```
public static Boolean isInvalidDob()
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(CreditMantriApplication.getCreditMantri());
    return preferences.getBoolean("dob",false);
}
```

here is my code for getting a second time true for invalidDob

Comment: Did you try use `boolean` instead if `Boolean`?

Comment: instead of edit.apply() try edit.commit();

Comment: yeah it worked thanks.. Zarul Izham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
edit.commit();
```

instead of

```
edit.apply();
```

As    edit.commit(); saves immediately while    edit.apply(); do in background

Comment: No, you should still use apply(). It will apply the changes immediately in memory so if you read from the same SharedPreferences (they are singletons within the same process) you will immediately get the new value. Only the physical save to disk is delayed. It's all written there in the documentation.